# Subfigures on next page does not continue numbering

Tags: subfloats

I am using the code below to separate 7 subfigures to 2 pages - the first page has 4 and second page has 3 figures. The figures on the second page starts counting from (a), but I want it to continue count from (e). How to achieve that?

```
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[format=hang,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=0,labelsep=period]{caption}

\begin{figure}[!b]
\centering
\subfigure[]{\label{fig:domain_eg4_10}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{2nd_figs/domain_eg4_10.png}}%
\subfigure[]{\label{fig:eta_eg4}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{2nd_figs/eta_3p4g2c_log.png}}
\subfigure[]{\label{fig:error_3p4g2c_x}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{2nd_figs/error_3p4g2c_log_x.png}}%
\subfigure[]{\label{fig:error_3p4g2c_eta}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{2nd_figs/error_3p4g2c_log_eta.png}}
\caption{Results of Example 4. (a) is the gain and phase boundaries at 10 simulation time. (b), (c), (d), (f), and (g) are, respectively, $\int_V\eta_2dV$ and $\int_V\eta_3dV$, percent error of $\int_Vx_{i,p}dV$, percent error of $\int_V\eta_2dV$, the number of global nonlinear iterations, and wall time plotted against simulation time for LSA and GSA. (e) shows the number of nested Newton iterations, $\eta_{10}$, $\eta_2$, $\eta_3$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ plotted horizontally along the center line at 0.19 simulation time in LSA.}
\label{fig:example4}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!t]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfigure[]{\label{fig:tiger_3p4g2c}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{2nd_figs/tiger_3p4g2c.png}}%
\subfigure[]{\label{fig:iter_3p4g2c}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{2nd_figs/iter_3p4g2c_log.png}}
\subfigure[]{\label{fig:wall_3p4g2c}\ContinuedFloat
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{2nd_figs/wall_3p4g2c_log.png}}
\caption{Continued.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I just figured it out. It's the position of \ContinuedFloat.

Comment: _The figures on the second page starts counting from (a), but I want it to continue count from (e)_; `\ContinedFloat` only prevents the main figure counter from advancing. One has to manually alter `subfigure` counter to achieve what you expect in the second environment, that is add the line `\addtocounter{subfigure}{n}`, where n=4 in OP's case.